# How to search for dataframes and sort each one accordingly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframes in my local named like `s1_down_threshold`, `s1_up_threshold`, `s2_down_threshold`,`s2_down_threshold`, `s19_down_threshold`, `s19_down_threshold` and so on.

I would like to sort the dataframes having 'down_threshold' in their names in descending order based on one column and the dataframes having 'up_threshold' in their names in ascending order based on the same column.

I know that I can use `.sort_values()` for each and every one of them, but I would like to know if there is a more efficient way to do it?

**I was hoping for something as follows:**

Going through the names of all the dataframes in my local and then finding the dataframes with 'down_threshold' in their names and sorting them accordingly and then repeating the same process for 'up_threshold'

**Edit 1:**

[image]

Comment: Hey @anky_91, I saved the dfs in a dict. How can I find the dataframes now that have `down_threshold` or `up_threshold` in their names in this dictionary?

Comment: Ok, so I created 2 different dicts, one for down_threshold & the other for up_threshold and sorted it according to your suggestions. Now, is there a way that the dataframes in these two different dicts replace the dataframes in my local?

Comment: I am not sure I get your question. Could you explain what do you mean?

Comment: by local, what do you mean? to you need to place them in a file in any directory. I am confused here, sorry

Comment: I added an image in the question that can help you understand how my dfs are stored

Comment: i have no idea how to do this, sorry. Normally i store my dfs in a dict whenever i am working with multiple dfs and referencing the keys I get my job done on whichever df I want to. Cheers..!! :)

Comment: I don't see any reason to have two dictionary

Comment: Hey @Feras I created 2 dicts because on each of them I have to do different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name the data frame before adding it to Dataframe dictionary like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json

#using sample data

data = {'id': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'value': [2000, 600, 400, 3000]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 =df.copy()
df2=df.copy()
df3=df.copy()
df4=df.copy()

DataFrameDict=[]

df1.name='s1_down_threshold'
DataFrameDict.append(df1)
df2.name='s2_down_threshold'
DataFrameDict.append(df2)
df3.name='s1_up_threshold'
DataFrameDict.append(df3)
df4.name='s2_up_threshold'
DataFrameDict.append(df4)

for i in range(len(DataFrameDict)):
    if ('down' in DataFrameDict[i].name):
        print (DataFrameDict[i].name,'sorted down')
        DataFrameDict[i].sort_values(by='value', ascending=False,inplace=True)
    elif ('up' in DataFrameDict[i].name):
        print (DataFrameDict[i].name,'sorted up')
        DataFrameDict[i].sort_values(by='value', ascending=True,inplace=True)

>>> DataFrameDict
[  id  value
3  D   3000
0  A   2000
1  B    600
2  C    400,   
   id  value
3  D   3000
0  A   2000
1  B    600
2  C    400,   
   id  value
2  C    400
1  B    600
0  A   2000
3  D   3000,   
   id  value
2  C    400
1  B    600
0  A   2000
3  D   3000]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your df's are saved in the csv format in the same folder you can use the os library to import all of them and use the split function to decide wether to sort them in ascending or in a descending fashion.

Here is what it could look like :

```
import os

for file in os.listdir('./folder1/'):
    pd.read_csv('folder1/' + file)
    if file.split('.')[0].split('_')[1] =='down':
        df.sort_values(ascending = False, inplace = True)
    elif file.split('.')[0].split('_')[1] =='up':
        df.sort_values(ascending = True, inplace = True)
    df.to_csv('folder1/' + file)
```

If there are other files in your local directory you can read the csv inside the if and elif conditions.

Comment: @anky_91 all his df have the same format (name_down/up_threshold), this allows us to identify if the file is named up or down and sort accordingly

Comment: But you are right it doesn't search for similar strings